# Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-webserver'

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

When I running the node.js project with gulp. I'm getting "Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-webserver'". Re-wrote the connection with below but still its same.

```
$ npm install --save-dev gulp-webserver
```

Comment: Can you share the code for your server?

Comment: @gnerkus `var gulp = require('gulp');
var webserver = require('gulp-webserver');
var fs = require('fs');
var minimist = require('minimist');
var xmllint = require('xmllint');
var chalk = require('chalk');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({ lazy: true });
var del = require('del');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var Xml2Js = require('xml2js');`

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the existance of the web server. 
Solution: Go to gulp location within your solution and use below..Solved!
`$ npm install --save-dev gulp-webserver`

This would be usefull..[enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-webserver)